# JQuery Left Panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there any plug in for jquery which enables left and right side panels. Like the one in most IDEs. When mouse goes over extreme left it appears similarly when mouse goes out of the panel it disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Extruder plug in
http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.extruder/extruder.html